# How to switch JUnit 5 test instance lifecycle to "per-class" in gradle 4.6+?

Tags: gradle, junit5

As gradle 4.6 supports JUnit 5 with following configuration.

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

It seems like the old way to change testinstance lifecycle doesn't work.

```
junitPlatform {
    // ...
    configurationParameter 'junit.jupiter.conditions.deactivate', '*'
    configurationParameters([
        'junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled': 'true',
        'junit.jupiter.testinstance.lifecycle.default': 'per_class'
    ])
    // ...
}
```

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-gradle-config-params

How to switch JUnit 5 test instance lifecycle to "per-class" in gradle 4.6+?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apart from using system property as described in [eee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49082417/1433665), `junit-platform.properties` file can be used. `junit-platform.properties` file can be put in `src/test/resources`.

**junit-platform.properties**

```
junit.jupiter.testinstance.lifecycle.default = per_class
```

Here's the answer from JUnit team. https://twitter.com/junitteam/status/970014414891094018

> Either set it as a systemProperty in the task, or set it in the
>   junit-platform.properties  file. The latter is the more robust
>   mechanism since it will be applied in the IDE as well.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with a system property:

```
test {

    useJUnitPlatform {
        // ...
        systemProperty 'junit.jupiter.testinstance.lifecycle.default', 'per_class'
        // ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, It works. I posted another solution as well.